# Plugin "Hello World!" for User onUserAuthorisation

Tags: plugin, user

I am trying to create a plugin to make some database queries from the [event onUserAuthorisation](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAuthorisation).  Right now I am just trying to set up a "Hello World" style plugin, because I am not sure yet that my plugin function is even firing correctly.  Right now the plugin should just send out an email when a new user gains authorisation.

I can confirm that the joomla emails work for user registration and administration.

Files: `autoextranet.php`,`autoextranet.xml`,`index.html`(empty)

autoextranet.php

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgUserAutoextranet extends JPlugin
{
    public function onUserAuthorisation($user, $options)
        {
        $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
        $config = JFactory::getConfig();

        $sender = array( 
            $config->get( 'mailfrom' ),
            $config->get( 'fromname' )
            );
        $mailer->setSender($sender);

        $recipient = array( 'email1@gmail.com', 'email2@some.com' );
        $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

        $body = "New User: ".$user->username;
        $mailer->setBody($body);

        $mailer->setSubject('You got a new user.');

        $mailer->Send();
        }
}

?>
```

autoextranet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.8.2" type="plugin" group="user">
        <name>PLG_USER_AUTOEXTRANET</name>
        <author>Tim DeLise</author>
        <creationDate>Nov 14, 2017</creationDate>
        <copyright>Tim D</copyright>
        <license>GNU General Public License</license>
        <authorEmail>your email</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>your website</authorUrl>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <description>.</description>
        <files>
                <filename plugin="autoextranet">autoextranet.php</filename>
                <filename>index.html</filename>
        </files>
</extension>
```

The problem now is that I have installed and activated the plugin.  When I create and activate a new user, I just get nothing.

Unfortunately I have limited access to the server, and haven't been able to view the PHP error logs.  I am looking for some way to confirm that the event is firing my code.  Any suggestion is welcome.  Also this is the first plugin I am making so maybe there is something wrong with my files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Joomla Version 3.8.2

Comment: Are you certain the onUserAuthorisation hook is being called?

Comment: @DavidHayes no, i guess not.  I figured it was from the description: `The system triggers this event after the user has been authenticated and before he has been signed in the website.` I am trying to trigger it by creating a new user and activating then using the email link.

Comment: I've run into issues before where my hook wasn't called. I would try putting a "echo 'inside'; exit;" right inside the onUserAuthorisation method then try to login just to verify it is called.

Comment: Also, the Joomla docs (https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User) on the onUserAuthorisation method mention this plugin as an example (https://github.com/ITPrism/Plugin-User-FaceControl). Coincidentally, it implements the exact functionality you are working on.